# Get database credentials from context.xml file

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have a java project that implements some APIs, in Eclipse.

I have `db.java` file that enables the communication with the MySQL database.

Instead of have the MySQL credentials in a java file, I would like to have them in `/META-INF/context.xml` file.

Do you know how to do this?

This is my current code:

```
public class db {

    private String userName = null;
    private String password = null;
    private String dbName = null;
    private String db_connect_string = null;

    public db() {
        this.db_connect_string = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
        this.dbName = "name";
        this.userName = "uname";
        this.password = "pass";
    }

protected Connection getDBMySQLCon() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        return DriverManager.getConnection(this.db_connect_string+"?useSSL=false",  this.userName, this.password);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: configure context params in `web.xml`

Comment: @Satya Can you give me an example please?

Comment: which technologies you are using.

Comment: @Satya  I'm using `java` and `apache tomcat 7.0`

Comment: which server side technologies are you using.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an XML file, you can have a properties file, that has the required information. Problem with XML file is that you will have to choose an XML parser and work with it.

If you want to go ahead with properties file you can consider the following snippet.

```
public void setProp() throws Exception{  
    FileReader reader=new FileReader("db.properties");  
    Properties p=new Properties();  
    p.load(reader);  
    // you can get values you want as properties using
    this.db_connect_string = p.getProperty("db_connect_string");  
    this.dbName = p.getProperty("dbName");  
}
```

And your file structure should be something like

```
db_connect_string=connection.string  
dbName=name
userName=uname
password=pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the environment of the container.

/META-INF/context.xml

The context.xml overides the tomcate context entry.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Specify a JDBC datasource -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydatabase" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="YOUR_USERNAME" 
              password="YOUR_PASSWORD"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://mysql.metawerx.net:3306/YOUR_DATABASE_NAME?
              autoReconnect=true"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              maxActive="10" 
              maxIdle="4"/>

</Context>

// Get DataSource
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatabase");
// Get Connection and Statement
Connection c = ds.getConnection();
Statement s = c.createStatement();
```